# I want to put the XML from a webpage into an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, cocoa-touch

How do i do this? Suggestions? I don't know how the xml page is encoded neither, if i need to know that, how do i find out?

Comment: You already asked this question, and I answered it for you.

Comment: Why the needless re-post? As @Evan Mulawski said, he already answered this on your previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an XML parser; [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) is a good place to get started. You can then extract parts of your XML doc and save as NSStrings.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of loading the XML data into an NSString, you can simply use the initWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error: method of the [NSString class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). (That said, if you find out the encoding, simply use the initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error: method instead.)